# jQuery mouse queue/ css change problem

Tags: jquery, css

```
$(next).click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(parseInt($(container).css('left')) <= (-(container_width-offset))) {
        $(container).animate({
                queue:false,
                left: "0px"
            }, speed, function() {

            });

    } else {
        $(container).animate({
                queue:false,
                left: "-="+offset+"px"
        }, speed, function() { });
    }
});
```

The preceding code animates a series of floating divs to slide left to right. It all works fine EXCEPT when someone clicks the mouse too quickly, the css doesn't update quick enough and sometimes it will roll to a blank div because this line doesn't register quick enough:
`parseInt($(container).css('left')) <= (-(container_width-offset))`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this line

```
if($(this).is(":animated")) return;
```

(after `event.preventDefault();`)

Comment: That is glorious. What is it doing?

Comment: it exits the function if the element is "animated", which means it is currently moving / fading / whatever